# Bash/Shell scripting

Tags: shell

What does the command `cp $1/. $2` do? I know cp is used for copying from source(stored in variable `$1`) to destination(stored in variable `$2`). I am just confused with the `/.` used along with the variable. Can someone please help me understand this?

Answer (score 1):

The command:

```
$ cp -R $1/. $2
```

copies contents of directory pointed by `$1` to the directory `$2`.

Without `-R` switch this command would fail both when `$1` is a file or directory.

In general, `.` points to the current directory. You can see that by comparing inode's shown by `ls`:

```
$ mkdir test
$ ls -ali
9525121 drwxr-xr-x   3 IU    wheel  102 23 mar 12:31 .
 771046 drwxrwxrwt  21 root  wheel  714 23 mar 12:30 ..
9525312 drwxr-xr-x   2 IU    wheel   68 23 mar 12:31 test

$ cd test
$ ls -ali
9525312 drwxr-xr-x  2 IU  wheel   68 23 mar 12:31 .
9525121 drwxr-xr-x  3 IU  wheel  102 23 mar 12:31 ..
```

Note that inode `9525312` points to `test` when viewed from the parent directory, and points to `.` when viewed from inside the `test` directory.